# Reuse of a worker instance to handle several tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have an application for web testing (based on Selenium but this should not matter much here) which executes quite a number of test cases successively. It takes a couple of hours to complete and the number of test cases grows so I would like to use multiple web browser instances to execute several test cases in parallel. The test cases have no dependency on each other.

Very simplified it looks like this:

```
TestExecutor executor = new TestExecutor(new FirefoxDriver());
for (TestCase test: tests) {
    executor.execute(test);
    // use results here
}
```

Now I do not know exactly how to parallelize this. I can easily create several TestExecutors connected to several web browsers as Callables and use Executors, CompletitionServices and other nice helper classes but how do I:

- pass a new TestCase to a TestExecutor once it is ready with the previous TestCase? The call() method in Callable takes no arguments, so I probably have to implement some setNextTestCase() in my TestExecutor class to achieve this which I don't find really nice. Are there any better alternatives?
- reuse the TestExecutor instance for the execution of the next test case? Since every TestExecutor instance requires a web browser instance it takes a long time to initialize it and would result in many windows flashing on the screen if I would create a new TestExecutor for every test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pass a new TestCase to a TestExecutor once it is ready with the previous TestCase?

This is a common question if I'm understanding you.  You have a number of threads in a thread-pool but each thread has some context -- in this case a "web browser".  You don't want to have to start up a new browser for every job submitted to the thread-pool.

Here are some ideas about how to accomplish this.

- Have a `BlockingQueue` of `TestCase` objects.  Each of your threads then initialize their browser and then dequeue from the queue of `TestCase` objects until the queue is empty or some shutdown boolean is set to true.  You could the submit your `TestExecutor` objects into a thread-pool, but they would do their own dequeuing of the `TestCase` objects though your own queue.  You would *not* submit the `TestCase` to the thread-pool.

  ```
  BlockingQueue<TestCase> testCaseQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  for (TestCase test: tests) {
      testCaseQueue.add(test);
  }
  // now make your executors and run them in a thread-pool
  TestExecutor testExecutor =
       new TestExecutor(new FirefoxDriver(), testCaseQueue);
  ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  threadPool.submit(testExecutor);
  ...
  // once you've submitted your last executor, you shutdown the pool
  threadPool.shutdown();

  ...
  // inside of the executor, they dequeue tests from `testCaseQueue`
  while (!shutdown) {
      TestCase testCase = testCaseQueue.poll(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      if (testCase == null) {
         break;
      }
      ...
  }
  ```
- Another idea would be to submit the `TestCase` to the thread pool and use a `ThreadLocal` to get the previously configured browser for the test.  This is not as optimal because it  makes it hard to terminate the browser appropriately when the tests have completed.

Comment: I see, thanks. But I don't get the point of using the ExecutorService in this case. What do we gain with it? No new tasks (which are TestExecutors in this case) are submitted during the run-time so the ExecutorService has actually nothing to schedule. I could just create a number of TestExecutors (passing the testCaseQueue in the c'tor like you suggested) as Thread instances and start() each of them. Right?

Comment: Yeah it is not necessary @Pinni.  A lot of people use `ExecutorService` always instead of instantiating `Thread` themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a `Queue` / `List` of `TestExecutors`. Then create a `Callable` / `Runnable` that wraps the `TestCase`. You `ExecutorService` would have the same number of threads as your `List` of `TestExecutors`. The first step of the `Runnable` would be to retrieve / pop a `TestExecutor` from the `Queue`. It would utilize the executor for the test then when done put it back in the queue.